# How can I dual boot 2 linux distros Keeping One as my primary and constantly change the second?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I would like to Dual boot my secondary laptop. I want to keep one Linux Distro  (Lets take Ubuntu..!) as my daily driver and try out different distros like Linux Mint, Fedora, Manjaro....etc. How can I configure my GRUB for constantly changing secondary distro?? I don't want to keep common /home folder for them; I just want to try out different distros for a week or may be couple of weeks. Please suggest me a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have Grub reinstalled each time you install a new system. If you don't use an encrypted partition for the first system, the new installation will detect it and add it to the Grub list. The effect is that you can use both the first and the new OS. This may not set your first OS as a default system (this is the only meaning your term 'primary' boils down to), but you can choose between them manually.

If you decide to use an encrypted partition for the first system, however, the situation is getting complex, and I can't help you with it.

And finally, I can't answer you if there's any way not to reinstall Grub at each new OS installation, but to keep some lasting and flexible configuration of it. This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach for trying out various different distributions is to use their Live CD versions. (Many distributions have these.) Install each one in turn to a USB and boot from that while you're trying it out. Remove the USB and you can boot from your usual preferred installation.

Unless you have an encrypted disk for your `$HOME` directory you will be able to access that easily enough from your temporary distribution as well as your preferred one.

Comment: I have done this; but I want to play around with that distro for at least 2~3 weeks to check how actually that particular distro runs on my laptop. I also don't prefer installing it on virtualbox or VMware.